# How do I stop my HTML table from losing it's data when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm busy with a ASP.net project that's written in VB and we're using Dev Express 16.1 for some of these UI elements.

This page displays a scroll able list of products which the user can click on, see more information on the product and then add it to a cart if they wish.

So that's the quick overview.

Firstly the scroll able list is populated from the server side, no issue here, the list has a client side click listener which fires when a product is clicked on, this uses ajax to call a web method which gets the extra information on the product, returns it as json and then displays it on the client side.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ClassName.aspx/DisplayProductInfo",
                data: '{productCode: "' + values + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: ReceiveResponse,
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.d);
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
```

The information is then displayed into tables which I build based on what I receive back as a response.

```
    function ReceiveResponse(response) {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.d)

document.getElementById('<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>').click();

                if (jsonResponse.ProductPrice.length > 0) {
                    var priceTable = "<tr id=\"suppNameRow\">";
                    for (var x = 0; x < jsonResponse.ProductPrice.length; x++) {
                        priceTable += "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductPrice[x].SupplierName + "</td>";
                    }
                    priceTable += "</tr>";
                    priceTable += "<tr id=\"suppPriceRow\">";
                    for (var y = 0; y < jsonResponse.ProductPrice.length; y++) {
                        priceTable += "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductPrice[y].SupplierPrice + "</td>";
                    }
                    priceTable += "</tr>";

                    document.getElementById('productPriceTableBody').innerHTML = priceTable;
                } else {
                    var suppPriceRow = document.getElementById('suppPriceRow').getElementsByTagName("td");
                    for (var z = 0; z < suppPriceRow.length; z++) {
                        suppPriceRow[z].innerText = "N/A"
                    }
                }

                var monthCells = document.getElementById('monthRow').getElementsByTagName("td");
                var historyTable = document.getElementById('productHistoryTable')

                if (jsonResponse.ProductHistory.length > 0) {
                    for (var z = 0; z < jsonResponse.ProductHistory.length; z++) {
                        for (var a = 1; a <= 12; a++) {
                            if (monthCells[a].innerText == jsonResponse.ProductHistory[z].Month) {
                                historyTable.rows[0].cells[a].innerText = jsonResponse.ProductHistory[z].MyQty;
                                historyTable.rows[2].cells[a].innerText = jsonResponse.ProductHistory[z].CompQty;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var a = 1; a <= 12; a++) {
                        historyTable.rows[0].cells[a].innerText = "0";
                        historyTable.rows[2].cells[a].innerText = "0";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've gone this route as the table needed to be dynamic. One issue I've encountered is trying to call a standard method on the server side from javascript, a workaround was to use a button's onclick to call that method, as seen in the second line of the response function. This is where the problem comes in.

```
Protected Sub loadProductPrices(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Not productKeyHolder.Value = "" Then

            Dim dtProdPrices As DataTable = pc.GetListedPrices(productKeyHolder.Value)
            gvListedPrices.DataSource = dtProdPrices
            gvListedPrices.KeyFieldName = "barcode"
            gvListedPrices.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

gvListedPrices is a dx:ASPxGridView which I use to show the prices, this is where the problem comes in, the page seems to reload and I lose the data that I display from the json response.

I have got the button and the Gridview in an update panel but this didn't solve the problem.

Quick overview, When the a product is clicked, an ajax query runs, gets product information which is displayed into an html table then a hidden button is clicked and a gridview is populated, then the page refreshes and I lose the information in the table.

I'd like to prevent the table from losing the data. The hidden button is just a workaround.

Comment: When you go on the server with a click event, it will refresh the page. Can you populate the price the same way you did your table, with ajax?

Comment: I think you will have to either re-fetch your data or persist it somehow.

Comment: @the_lotus Hmm If i could find away to send a json object from the server side and receive it this could work.

Comment: @Demonic218 you already do it with DisplayProductInfo

Comment: @the_lotus That's being called from the Ajax method, I thought that was the only way to receive Json on the client side ?